# Eliding pronominal adverbs for infinitives

Tags: infinitive, pronominal-adverb

Can pronominal adverbs be “elided” when an infinitive follows them? — for example:

> Ich habe Angst **davor**, verrückt zu werden.

In the sentence above, *davor* takes the clause *verrückt zu werden* as an argument (compare e.g. *Ich habe [Angst [vor Hunden]<sub>PP</sub>]<sub>NP</sub>*). However, I’ve often heard phrases like this in spoken German “leaving out” the pronominal adverb … but, today, I even saw the phenomenon in written form:

> Ich habe Angst, verrückt zu werden.

*(Taken from an advertisement by [the Berliner Krisendienst](http://www.berliner-krisendienst.de/))*

Are these two sentences (one with and without the pronominal adverb) completely interchangeable? If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important answer first: Yes, from the semantical point of view your two sentences mean absolutely the same. In fact, the second one is often preferred as it sounds more natural and less artificial.

Gramatically spoken, the sentences are somehow different. Having a look at the possibilities to use [infinitive constructions](http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Ortho/V_Infinitiv_Skript.pdf) you see that in both cases the infinitive construction is what we call "satzwertig" (like a sentence).

In the first case the infinitive group is dependent on the pronominal adverb (**"Korrelat"**) whereas the infinitive group in the second case is dependent on the noun "Angst" (**"attributive Infinitivgruppe"**).

Comment: Ironically enough, my answer [was edited to change "subordinate clause" to "infinitive"](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/33160/revisions).

Comment: You are right. Infinitive group is the correct term - my answer was unprecise at first. I changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I know the phrase “Angst haben” as stand-alone, or in these constructs:

1. “Angst haben **zu**” + *infinitive*
   (extended: “Angst haben **, … zu**” + *infinitive*)
2. “Angst haben, **dass**” - *attributive clause*
3. “**Vor** jemandem/etwas Angst haben”
   (extended: “**davor,** + *attributive clause*
   or: “**vor dem/allem,** + *attributive clause*)
4. “**Um** jemanden/etwas Angst haben”
   (extended: “**darum,** + *attributive clause*
   or: “**um das/alles,** + *attributive clause*)

Your sentences are the extended forms of 3. and 1. resp. You may also say:

> Ich habe Angst, dass ich verrückt werde. (Form 2.)
>
> Ich habe Angst vor dem Verrücktwerden. (Form 3.)
>
> Ich habe Angst um meine geistige Gesundheit. (Form 4.)

Note, that forms 1. and 2. are restricted to *what **you** might do* (1.) and *what might happen* (2.). With 3. you may name arbitrary things, persons, conditions, or actions (yours and another's). I for one prefer form 1. or 2., if appropriate.